# How to parameterize the size of cuda.local.array in Numba?

Tags: python, arrays, cuda, local, numba

I want to allocate a small local array in a Numba CUDA kernel. However, I find that it does not allow parameterized array size. Only a constant size is allowed. How can I solve this?

```
import numba

# This works, but it has to hard code the array size
@cuda.jit
def kernel1():
    arr = numba.cuda.local.array(3, dtype=numba.float32)

kernel1[2,2]()


# I want this, but it does not work
@cuda.jit
def kernel2(dim):
    arr = numba.cuda.local.array(dim, dtype=numba.float32)

kernel2[2,2](3)
```

Below is the error message

```
TypingError: Failed in cuda mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function local.array at 0x7f074e54dee0>) found for signature:
 
 >>> array(int64, dtype=class(float32))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 2 did not match due to:
  Overload of function 'array': File: numba/cuda/cudadecl.py: Line 44.
    With argument(s): '(int64, dtype=class(float32))':
   No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<function local.array at 0x7f074e54dee0>)
During: typing of call at /tmp/ipykernel_18276/1701838372.py (3)


File "../../../../../tmp/ipykernel_18276/1701838372.py", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

Comment: You can’t. This isn’t supported in any form of CUDA, local memory is statically allocated

Comment: If I remember right, variables from outside the definition of the kernel are taken as constants inside the kernel due to the JIT compilation. So there might be a way to do it, but each version of the kernel will be separately compiled, so you don't want to have too many versions. Also you still wont be able to get differing sizes between threads if that was one of your use-cases.

Comment: I think @paleonix's answer is the best I can get. A global variable works like a macro constant in CUDA C++ and nearly suffices for the "parameterizing" purpose with JIT.

Answer (score 3):

> I find that it does not allow parameterized array size. Only a constant size is allowed. How can I solve this?

You can’t. As you say, only a constant size is allowed. This isn’t a Numba limitation, it is limitation of the  CUDA programming model. Thread local memory is always statically allocated by the compiler.

There may be some meta-programming tricks you can try, analogous to C++ templates, but that will only leave you with multiple versions of the kernel  with different statically compiled local array sizes, not true runtime dynamic allocation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Now I use a global variable instead of a function argument to "parameterize" the dimension, as @paleonix suggested.